# Cannot find module @angular/core + angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to create an Angular 2 application using Typescript in Visual Studio 2015. I have installed npm on my machine. When I compile my application , I am getting errors cannot find module '@angular/core'. 
It is referred in all the ts files under the node_modules folder in the import statement.
For e.g.

```
import { ElementRef, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck, EventEmitter, IterableDiffers } from '@angular/core';
```

I am currently getting around 500 plus errors. The error goes off when I replace it with  'angular2/core '. Also just to let you know , I am using PrimeNG UI Components in my project as well.

Could somebody help ? I don't understand why it is looking at @angular/core ?

Comment: I suggest using https://cli.angular.io/ . See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHZe6gGI5RY

Comment: Thanks. Can I include the code structure generated by cli.angular.io into my visual studio solution

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `angular2` name in modules names is for versions before RC (release candidate) versions (beta ones) and the `@angular` one for RC versions.

Comment: I am using angular2 2.0.0-beta.17 version. So then what is the problem

Comment: So you need to use: import { ... } from 'angular2/core';

Comment: I am bit confused now. When I execute npm install angular2, it installs ngular2 2.0.0-beta.17 version. How do I install the release candidate version. As I need to use the latest.

Comment: In fact there are several packages to install for rc versions: @angular/core, ...

Comment: see this link for more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 5):

1. Install nodejs
2. Open cmd prompt and type 'cd *your project directory*'
3. Type 'npm install' and hit enter.

This will create a node_modules folder within that directory which should have the @angular/core that's required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really saved my time !

Answer (score 2):

You first need to add typings at global level as below.

```
npm install -g typings
```

Then create typings.json using below command.

```
typings init
```

Paste below code in typings.json

```
{
  "name": "ng2-application",
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

Now you need to add below code in tsconfig.json

```
 "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
       }
```

After doing above steps you will able to get definitions on F12.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, it would come and go depending on the module kind I had selected.  (Visual Studio, right-click project, properties, Typescript tab. It would occur for the "System" Module System, which is used in Angular2 QuickStart tutorial, but not for some others, for example.)

I verified the folder /node_modules/@angular/core/ existed in the proj and was populated.

Solution was to edit the .csproj file and add the line `<TypeScriptModuleResolution>Node</TypeScriptModuleResolution>` in both Debug and Release sections.  VS defaults to Classic for this setting for some settings of ModuleKind.