# Cannot find module '@angular/core'. Cannot find module 'rxjs'

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

### Environment:

OS: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit 
NPM: 5.6.0 
Node: v10.0.0 
Ionic: 3.20.0

### How I receive this error

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKajGwYe4TI) to apply firebase to an ionic project using angularfire2. I follow the tutorial exactly until I receive an error while running

```
$ ionic serve
```

The full error is like this:

```
typescript: home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts, line: 1 
Cannot find module '@angular/core'. 

L1:  import { InjectionToken, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
L2:  import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

typescript: home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts, line: 2 
Cannot find module 'rxjs'. 

L1:  import { InjectionToken, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
L2:  import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
L3:  import { FirebaseOptions, FirebaseAppConfig } from '@firebase/app-types';

typescript: home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts, line: 3 
Cannot find module '@angular/core'. 

L2:  import { FirebaseOptions, FirebaseAppConfig } from '@firebase/app-types';
L3:  import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
L4:  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

typescript: home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts, line: 4 
Cannot find module 'rxjs'. 

L3:  import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
L4:  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
L5:  export declare class AngularFireAuth {

typescript: home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts, line: 1 
Cannot find module '@angular/core'. 

L1:  import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
L2:  import { FirebaseApp as _FirebaseApp, FirebaseOptions, FirebaseAppConfig } from '@firebase/app-types';
```

### Traceback

Tracing back, when I was installing angularfire2 through command line, I run this command ([following the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2))

```
npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
```

And it returns this:

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EAI_AGAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of @firebase/app@^0.1.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bin@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN bin@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.7
+ firebase@5.0.2
updated 2 packages in 80.502s
```

Then I try to run the same command again, now it returns almost the same as above but without the **npm WARN registry**.

```
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bin@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN bin@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

The file **package.json** is located in /home/brian and it contains the lines below.

```
{
  "name": "bin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.8.0",
    "cordova": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.0.2",
    "ionic": "^3.20.0",
    "npm": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

There is this text in browser after i run $ ionic serve

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.9
Angular Core: 5.2.10
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.10
Node: 10.0.0
OS Platform: Linux 4.4
Navigator Platform: Linux x86_64
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
```

> I think I installed angularfire on the same location as npm and node,
>   because I run all these installation command in my default location
>   when opening command line. It should be in /home/brian. I also have
>   this folder /home/brian/node_modules.

### My Google research to solve this

[This similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213055/cannot-find-module-angular-core-angular2) says that we need to rename @angular to @angular2, but I found it returns same error.

Does anyone ever experience the same issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's you current version of `angular`?

Comment: can you include the package.json in your question?

Comment: Hi @SurajRao thanks for your suggestion. it is updated.

Comment: Hi @Pengyy according to the file package.json, the angular version is 1.7.0 . Is there any other way to check angular version? I cannot check using angular -v or angular --version .

Comment: angular 1.7? 6.* is released

Comment: @Antoniossss it is Angular CLI

Answer (score 4):

Based on you version info of `ionic` **v 3.9.2**, you need to install `angular V4.4.6`, refer ionic **[dependencies](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/v3.9.2/package.json)**. BTW, when you don't declare the exact version you want to install, `npm` will install the **latest version by default**.

You can use below command:

```
// all angular packages listed in above dependencies 
npm install @angular/[package-name]@4.4.6
```

And based on version of angular packages, you should install `AngularFire2` **[**v5.0.0-rc.3](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/5.0.0-rc.3/package.json)**** and `rxjs` of **[v5.0.1+(not v6.x)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.6/package.json)**.

```
npm install firebase@4.5.0 angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
npm install rxjs@5.0.1 --save
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have ran:  $ npm install firebase angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save,  so my package.json now is "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3". However I still got the exact same error when running $ ionic serve. Any other idea?

Comment: @BrianIvanderT.P. same error means `Cannot find module '@angular/core'. `? have you installed `@angular/core@4.4.6`?

Comment: Great catch @pengyy ! I run `$ npm install @angular/core@4.4.6` and `$ npm install rxjs@5.0.1 --save`  ,  now that "Cannot find module" has gone. But I have another typescript error.

Comment: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'. Property 'functions' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'. home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts

Comment: `export declare const FirebaseAppConfigToken: InjectionToken<FirebaseAppConfig>;
export declare class FirebaseApp implements firebase.app.App {
name: string;`

Comment: @BrianIvanderT.P. you need firebase of **v4.5.0**. checked my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Pengyy. I have run `npm install firebase@4.5.0 angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save` but when Iook at my package.json in my /home/brian/package.json, it is still `"firebase": "^5.0.2"`

Comment: @BrianIvanderT.P. Try with `npm uninstall firebase --save` and reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pengyy, your suggestion is really close to fix it, just need to add one more step.

This error is caused by the non compatible versions I used accross ionic - @angular/core - firebase - angularfire2 - and rxjs.

The way I solve it is is following @Pengyy's answer:

In my home folder `/home/brian`run

1. `npm install @angular/[package-name]@4.4.6`
2. `npm install firebase@4.5.0 angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save`
3. `npm install rxjs@5.0.1 --save`

Then need to do one more step: in my ionic project folder where I run ionic serve, (e.g. project name is myApp the folder is `/home/brian/myApp`) run this command.

1. `npm install firebase@4.5.0`

---

This last step is necessary, otherwise I still got an error

```
Runtime Error 
Cannot find module "firebase/auth"
```

---

This problem is solved!